# Failed opening required 'Net/SSH2.php'?

Tags: centos, phpseclib, libssh2

I have installed SSH2 as per [these instructions](http://programster.blogspot.com/2013/06/centos-64-install-ssh2-extension-for-php.html). I also checked in PHPInfo, and I can see SSH is working. I.e. It is showing up. However, my code still bombs:

[image]

It bombs out with:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Net/SSH2.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php/phpseclib') 
in SSHConnect.class.inc on line 5
```

I tried:

```
locate SSH2.php
```

And it can't find the files anywhere. So I really have no idea why this is not working? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed libssh2 and are trying to use phpseclib. If you want to use phpseclib you can install it via composer or via PEAR. Or you can just go to http://phpseclib.sourceforge.org , download the *.zip and put it where-ever you like, so long as it's in the include_path.